# Url not changing when typing manually when using React-Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import LandingPage from "./Components/LandingPage"
import RegistrationForm from "./Components/RegistrationForm"
import LoginForm from "./Components/LoginForm"
import NotFoundPage from "./Components/NotFoundPage"

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                        <Route path="/register" component={RegistrationForm} />
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginForm} />
                        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default App
```

So, I have this routing set up in App.js and when I go to **localhost:3000/register** or login, it just shows **Not Found 404**. It's not the NotFoundPage that I have as a component. Interestingly, when I used HashRouter, the URL seems to be working when entered manually. I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: How are you hosting the app? Webpack dev server? Express server?

Comment: Do you mean in the scripts of package.json?

Comment: I mean when you build and serve the application (yes, probably via a NPM script) where is it being served from? Do you use something like `create-react-app` which does hosting, or have you made a custom express server to host the react app from, or what

Comment: Yes, I'm serving from the express server. I've just added * in index.js, and it's working now. Wow!


```
router.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Comment: ok cool. It's technically an express issue, if you want a more detailed explanation including why hash router fixed it and all that, check the accepted answer for this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually

Comment: @Jayce444 do you the concept behind the wildcard route *? Why did it work after I added *?